# Inline submenu when hover

Tags: html, css, menu

This is my current menu:

[image]

And here what I want:

[image]

First submenu is inline, and the child is dropdown.

I'm trying to change the `ul li a` `display` to `inline-block` but seems like it not working at all. How I suppose to do to make the submenu hover **inline**, and the child of the submenu **dropdown**?

Thank you so much.

```css
#info {
top: 8%;
color: #fff;
height: auto;
font-family: arial;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
width: 72px;
z-index: 40;
border-radius: 4px;
background: dimgrey;

}

nav ul ul {
 display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
nav ul {
 background: #efefef;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
 content: ""; 
 clear: both; 
 display: inline;
}
nav ul li {
 position:relative;
 width:70px;
}
nav ul li:hover {
 background: #4b4b4b;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:hover  button{
 color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 12px 20px;
 color: #757575; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li  button{
 display: block;
 padding: 12px 25px;
 color: #757575; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
 background: #5f6975; 
 border-radius: 0px; 
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute; 
 top:0;
 left:100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
 padding: 12px 25px;
 color: #fff;
} 
nav ul ul li  button{
 padding: 12px 25px;
 color: #fff;
 height: 50px; width: 100px; margin-bottom: 2px; font-size: 18px;
} 
nav ul ul li a:hover {
 background: #4b4b4b;
}

nav ul ul ul {
 position: absolute; 
 left: 100%; 
 top:0;
}

.menu-container {padding: 19px 0; width: 70px; float: left;}
.clear {clear: both;}
ul{list-style:none;
border:0;outline:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
/* Vertical Mega Menu Styles */
.mega-menu{
font: bold 13px Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 16px;
background: #333;
border-left: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
position: relative; /* Required */
}
.mega-menu li a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
text-decoration: none;
border-top: 1px solid #555;
border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
border-right: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
}
.mega-menu li button {
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
text-decoration: none;
border-top: 1px solid #555;
border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
border-right: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
}
.mega-menu li a:hover, .mega-menu li.mega-hover a {
background: #4b4b4b;
color: #fff;
border-right: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
}
```

```html
 <div id="info">
     <!-- 
      <li><button id="FreehandPolyline">Freehand Polyline</button></li>
      <li><button id="Triangle">Triangle</button></li>
      <li><button id="Extent">Rectangle</button></li>
      <li><button id="Circle">Circle</button></li>
      <li><button id="Ellipse">Ellipse</button></li>
      <li><button id="Polygon">Polygon</button></li>
      <li><button id="FreehandPolygon">Freehand Polygon</button></li> -->
  <!-- <div id="menu_plotting" >Menu plotting</div> -->
  <nav class="menu-container clear">
   <ul id="mega-1" class="mega-menu">
   
                        <li>
                         <a title="Plotting Toolbar"><img src="assets/icon/pencil.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                         <ul>
                          <li><a title="Arrows"><img src="assets/icon/arrow.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                              <ul>
                                <li>
                                  <a title="Straight Arrow" onClick="urlicon('arrow','')" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                   <img src="assets/icon/arrow0.png" width="30" height="30"></a>

                                   <!-- <a id="a" class="btn btn-info" onclick="arrow_('arrow')" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                   <img src="icon/arrow.png" width="30" height="30"></a> -->
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <a title="Down Arrow" onClick="urlicon('arrow_l','')" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                   <img src="assets/icon/bawah.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <a title="Up Arrow" onClick="urlicon('arrow_a','')" style="cursor: pointer;"> <img src="assets/icon/atas.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a title="Polyline"><img src="assets/icon/polyline-48.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                             <ul>
                              <li><a title="Polyline" id="Polyline" onClick="urlicon('polyline','')"><img src="assets/icon/polyline.png" width="30" height="30">
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a title="Freehand Polyline" id="FreehandPolyline"><img src="assets/icon/freepolyline.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
                             </ul>
                            
                          </li>
                          <li><a title="Polygon"><img src="assets/icon/polygon.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                           <ul>
                            <li><a title="Polygon" id="Polygon" onClick="urlicon('polygon','')">
                                <img src="assets/icon/polygon.png" width="30" height="30">
                              </a>
                           </li>
                           <li><a title="Triangle" id="Triangle"><img src="assets/icon/triangle.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
             <li><a title="Rectangle" id="Extent"><img src="assets/icon/rectangle.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
             <li><a title="Circle" id="Circle"><img src="assets/icon/circle.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
             <li><a title="Ellipse" id="Ellipse"><img src="assets/icon/ellips.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
             <li><a title="Freehand Polygon" id="FreehandPolygon"><img src="assets/icon/freepolygon.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
                           </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>
         <a title="Text" onClick="select_text()"> <img src="assets/icon/font.png" alt="Text" width="30" height="30"> </a>
        </li>
          
                         </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="Radar"><img src="assets/icon/radar.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
                        <li><a title="Manuver"><img src="assets/icon/airplane.png" width="30" height="30"></a></li>
                         
                        
          <!-- ASOPS -->
        <?php } if ($list['asisten']==1 || $list['asisten']==6) {?>
   <li>
    <a title="Obstacle" onClick="select_obst()"><img src="assets/icon/obstacle.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a title="Strength" onClick="select_kekuatan()"><img src="assets/icon/streng.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a title="Unit" onClick="select_unit()"><img src="assets/icon/icons8-Org Unit-48.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a title="Situation" onClick="select_situasi()"><img src="assets/icon/warning.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
   </li>
    
    <?php if($list['asisten']==6 && $_SESSION['menu_'] == "menu"){ ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById("info3").style.display = "block";
      </script>
      <?php 
     }
      }
    } ?>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div style="font-size: 13px; margin-left: -20px;" id="nm_scen"><?php echo $_SESSION['scen1']; ?></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Here I provide the https://jsfiddle.net/qw8vpsbb/1/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I strongly suggest you add the link to the fiddle to the question, not the comments.

Comment: Sorry but my reputation isn't enough for adding more than 2 links.

Comment: In that case, use a stackoverflow snippet

Comment: Okay, I've add a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to specify a fixed width to the inner `UL` because by default it will have `100%` of the width of its relative positioned ancestor, and that width is not enough to have more than one item per line in the second menu level.

```
nav>ul>li>ul {
  width: 291px
}
```

Hope this helps.

```css
#info {
  top: 8%;
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  font-family: arial;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  z-index: 40;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: dimgrey;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}

nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #4b4b4b;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li:hover button {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li button {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  background: #5f6975;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 12px 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul ul li button {
  padding: 12px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b4b4b;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  width: 291px
}

.menu-container {
  padding: 19px 0;
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Vertical Mega Menu Styles */

.mega-menu {
  font: bold 13px Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
  background: #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
  position: relative;
  /* Required */
}

.mega-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  border-right: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
}

.mega-menu li button {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  border-right: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
}

.mega-menu li a:hover,
.mega-menu li.mega-hover a {
  background: #4b4b4b;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <!-- 
      <li><button id="FreehandPolyline">Freehand Polyline</button></li>
      <li><button id="Triangle">Triangle</button></li>
      <li><button id="Extent">Rectangle</button></li>
      <li><button id="Circle">Circle</button></li>
      <li><button id="Ellipse">Ellipse</button></li>
      <li><button id="Polygon">Polygon</button></li>
      <li><button id="FreehandPolygon">Freehand Polygon</button></li> -->
  <!-- <div id="menu_plotting" >Menu plotting</div> -->
  <nav class="menu-container clear">
    <ul id="mega-1" class="mega-menu">

      <li>
        <a title="Plotting Toolbar"><img src="assets/icon/pencil.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a title="Arrows"><img src="assets/icon/arrow.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a title="Straight Arrow" onClick="urlicon('arrow','')" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  <img src="assets/icon/arrow0.png" width="30" height="30"></a>

                <!-- <a id="a" class="btn btn-info" onclick="arrow_('arrow')" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                   <img src="icon/arrow.png" width="30" height="30"></a> -->
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Down Arrow" onClick="urlicon('arrow_l','')" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  <img src="assets/icon/bawah.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Up Arrow" onClick="urlicon('arrow_a','')" style="cursor: pointer;"> <img src="assets/icon/atas.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Polyline"><img src="assets/icon/polyline-48.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a title="Polyline" id="Polyline" onClick="urlicon('polyline','')"><img src="assets/icon/polyline.png" width="30" height="30">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Freehand Polyline" id="FreehandPolyline"><img src="assets/icon/freepolyline.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Polygon"><img src="assets/icon/polygon.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a title="Polygon" id="Polygon" onClick="urlicon('polygon','')">
                  <img src="assets/icon/polygon.png" width="30" height="30">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Triangle" id="Triangle"><img src="assets/icon/triangle.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Rectangle" id="Extent"><img src="assets/icon/rectangle.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Circle" id="Circle"><img src="assets/icon/circle.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Ellipse" id="Ellipse"><img src="assets/icon/ellips.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a title="Freehand Polygon" id="FreehandPolygon"><img src="assets/icon/freepolygon.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Text" onClick="select_text()"> <img src="assets/icon/font.png" alt="Text" width="30" height="30"> </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Radar"><img src="assets/icon/radar.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Manuver"><img src="assets/icon/airplane.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
      </li>


      <!-- ASOPS -->
      <?php } if ($list['asisten']==1 || $list['asisten']==6) {?>
      <li>
        <a title="Obstacle" onClick="select_obst()"><img src="assets/icon/obstacle.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Strength" onClick="select_kekuatan()"><img src="assets/icon/streng.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Unit" onClick="select_unit()"><img src="assets/icon/icons8-Org Unit-48.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Situation" onClick="select_situasi()"><img src="assets/icon/warning.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
      </li>

      <?php if($list['asisten']==6 && $_SESSION['menu_'] == "menu"){ ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("info3").style.display = "block";
      </script>
      <?php 
     }
      }
    } ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div style="font-size: 13px; margin-left: -20px;" id="nm_scen">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['scen1']; ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks! It's really helpful! I'll vote up soon when my reputation enough :D